# Free objects as term algebras in universal algebra and free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, vector-spaces, model-theory, universal-algebra

In universal algebra a general algebra has a [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)), that is a finite set of sort, which together form the universe, and relational symbols, functional symbols and symbols for constants. Additionaly, certain equations are stated. In this setting, a free algebra over some set $X$ of generators is given as the [Term algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_algebra) modulo the stated laws. If $X$ is countable, the free algebra could itself be at most countable. This could be looked up for example in [these lecture notes](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/UA-Valeriote.pdf), see Proposition 13 and the explanation of it.

I thought I have understood these notions, for example consider the signature of a single sorted algebra $(S, s, 0)$ where $S$ is the universe, $s$ the successor function, and $0$ a constant with the usual first order peano laws, then the term algebra would be all term $0, s(0), s(s(0)), s(s(s(0))), \ldots$ giving essentially the natural numbers.

But then I thought about vector spaces, or modules over a ring. And these could be written over a two-sorted signature. Now a vector space is always finitely generated, but the term algebra over some set of generators is certainly not a free object (or isomorphic to the vector space, as the vector space itself is free).

So why that, where exactly do the notions of universal algebra break down here? As I see it, if we define a generating set as a set such that every element could be written in terms of the operations with just these elements, then certainly the term algebra would work, but if we define a generating set as a set such that the mininal substructure containing this set equals the whole algebra as in the module case, then the term algebra over a generating set would not work.

> So, the discrepancy is that in universal algebra the free algebras are exactly the term algebras, and any two free algebras are isomorphic as [stated here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/algebra/#Free), but in the case of vector spaces, every vector space is itself free, but is certainly not isomorphic to its term algebra! So could anyone explain this discrepancy?

Comment: Some things to note: 1) in the multi-sorted case, the algebras will consist of multiple "carrier" sets, one for each sort; 2) we can view $R$-modules or $k$-vector spaces as algebras for a single sorted theory if we view scaling as a $R$-/$k$-indexed family of unary operations with the appropriate equations; 3) fields are not the algebras of an equational theory due to the $0\neq 1$ axiom (or equivalents).

Comment: Further to Derek Elkins' comment, even if you were to allow $0 = 1$ in a field, the law of reciprocals $xx^{-1} = 1$ is conditional on $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, fields are problematic because their theory is not equational. So let's think about modules over a ring (with $1$). To get an analogue of the term algebra for modules over a ring, you have two choices:

1) If you work in the category of modules over a fixed ring $R$, then you need to work in a single-sorted theory where variables denote module elements and the signature comprises $0$, $+$, and a function symbol $\mu_r(\cdot)$ for each $r \in R$ denoting the action of $r$ on the module. Given a set of variables $X$, the term algebra generated by this language and taken modulo all equations that hold in every $R$-module, will be a free module with basis $X$.

2) If you want to work over a two-sorted language with a sort $\cal R$ for ring elements and a sort $\cal M$ for module elements, then you need to work in a category which lets the rings vary as well as the modules. So objects would be pairs $(R, M)$ where $R$ is a ring and $M$ is an $R$-module. A morphism $f : (R_1, M_1)\to (R_2, M_2)$ would be a pair $(g, h)$ where $g$ is a ring homomorphism from $R_1$ to $R_2$ and $h$ is a module homomorphism from $M_1$ to $M_2$ with the latter viewed as an $R_1$-module via the action of $R_1$ on $M_2$ induced by the action of $R_2$ on $M_2$ via $g$. A free object in this category would be parametrised by a pair of sets $X$ and $Y$, where the elements of $X$ generate the ring and the elements of $Y$ generate the module and would constitute $(\Bbb{Z}[x_X], \Bbb{Z}[x_X]\langle Y \rangle)$ (see note on notation below). If you work over a signature for the two-sorted theory that represents the ring and module operations in the natural way, then $(\Bbb{Z}[x_X], \Bbb{Z}[x_X]\langle Y \rangle)$ is isomorphic to the term algebra generated by $X$ viewed as a set of variables of sort $\cal R$ and $Y$ viewed as a set of variables of sort $\cal M$ modulo the equations that hold in every ring and in every module over a ring.

Notation: in the above, I am using $R[x_X]$ for the ring of polynomials whose variables are indexed by the set $X$ (i.e., the free $R$-algebra generated by $X$) and $R\langle Y \rangle$ for the free $R$-module with basis $Y$.